# If $E$ is a closed set there exist a set $S$ such as $E=S'$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In "Elementary Real Analysis" by Thomson-Bruckner p.190 I did the following exercise: (we're working on $\mathbb{R}$ and elementary topology on that set)

> One of Cantor's early results in set theory is that for every closed set $E$ there is a set $S$ with $E=S'$. Attempt a proof.

My proof was pretty long and complicated and whatever I'd like to know other proofs because each proof can teach something new. I looked in Internet but I couldn't find any proof whatever I type on Google. Can you please tell me if you know any?

**Edit**: $S'$ is the set of limit points (accumulation points) of $S$.

Comment: What does the notation $S'$ mean here? Is it the set of limit points of $S$?

Comment: Just to clarify, what is $S'$ with regard to $S$?

Comment: Sorry for that I'll clarify it

Comment: @Scientifica you should also include your current proof, or at least an outline of it

Comment: @graydad Ok I'll put an outline.

Comment: Hint: $E = E' \cup (E\setminus E')$. What can you say about $E\setminus E'$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer All I can say is that $E\backslash E'$ it's not a closed set because if you take an accumulation point of $E\backslash E'$ then it's an accumulation point of $E$ and so is in $E'$ then not in $E$.

Comment: $E\setminus E'$ can be closed, for example if $E' = \varnothing$. But you found that $(E\setminus E')' \cap (E\setminus E') = \varnothing$, that is important. What does that mean?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer yes you're right so guess it's when $E'\neq\emptyset$ that $E\backslash E'$ isn't closed. But I think that $(E\backslash E')'\neq\emptyset$ for example $E=\{ 0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}/n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. $E'=\{ 0\}\subset E$ thus $E$ is closed. And $E\backslash E'=\{\frac{1}{n}/n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. We still have $(E\backslash E')'=\{ 0\}$. In fact $(E\backslash E')'\subset E'$ but can't prove the equality.

Comment: Oops, I meant $(E\setminus E')' \cap (E\setminus E') = \varnothing$ (fixed that now). Whether $E\setminus E'$ is closed or not isn't important. It can be closed also if $E'\neq \varnothing$. But what does $(E\setminus E')' \cap (E\setminus E') = \varnothing$ imply about the points of $E\setminus E'$?

Comment: If it can be also if $E'\neq\emptyset$ then even $E'=E$ or I made a mistake in my comment saying that "any accumulation point of $E\backslash E'$ is an accumulation point of $E$ (since $E\backslash E'\subset E$) and so an element of $E'$ then not in $E\backslash E'$? Anyway when we have more generally $F\cap F'=\emptyset$ then all points of $F$ are isolated points. So all points of $E\backslash E'$ are isolated points of $E\backslash E'$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen your last comment. Since there have others commented here, I don't get notified without `@`-pinging. No, you are not mistaken. And "isolated point" is exactly what I was aiming at. We have even a bit more, the points of $E\setminus E'$ are isolated points of $E$. Now, can you for an $x\in E\setminus E'$ construct a set $S_x$ such that $S_x' = \{x\}$? And then, can you arrange it so that for $$S = \bigcup_{x\in E\setminus E'} S_x$$ we have $S' = E\setminus E'$?

Comment: @DanielFischer No problem in fact all thanks to you. $E\backslash E'\neq\emptyset$ if $E\neq E'$. For every $x\in E\backslash E'$ we can take $S_x=\{x+\frac{1}{n}/n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Obviously $S_x'=\{x\}$. Then taking $S=\bigcup\limits_{x\in E\backslash E'}S_x$ we have $S'=\bigcup\limits_{x\in E\backslash E'}S_x'=E\backslash E'$ thus $E=E'\cup S'=(E\cup S)'$. That's a much easier proof thanks a lot for your help step by step I like it! But the problem is that we didn't use the hypothesis of $E$ being close. Am I mistaken or it really means that it's always true even for not closed sets?

Comment: You cannot always take $S_x=\bigl\{ x+\frac{1}{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\bigr\}$, that could introduce new accumulation points that do not belong to $E$. If say $E=\{0\}\cup\{ 2^{-k-1} : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, then that construction would give you $1, \frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{6},\dotsc$ as accumulation points of $S$ that are not in $E$. You need to modify the construction (but you can always take a subset of your $S_x$). Since the set $A'$ of accumulation points of $A$ is always closed, the closedness of $E$ is a necessary condition. If $E$ is not closed, then $E'\not\subset E$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So my mistake was generalizing $(A\cup B)'=A'\cup B'$ to an infinite number of sets. I'll think of the modification!

Comment: @DanielFischer I think I'm done. Let $x\in E\backslash E'$. It's an isolated point so $\exists\delta (x) >0,\,(x-\delta (x),x+\delta (x))\cap (E\backslash E')=\{ x\}$. Then set $S_x=\{ x+\frac{1}{n} /n\ge N\}$ where $n$ and $N$ are positive integers and $N$ is chosen such as $\forall n\ge N,\,(x+\frac{1}{n})\in (x-\delta (x),x+\delta (x))$. Set $S=\bigcup\limits_{x\in E\backslash E'}S_x$. Let $a\in S'$. We prove that $\exists ! x\in E\backslash E',\,a\in(x-\delta (x),x+\delta (x))$ and then that $a=x$. Thus $S'\subset E\backslash E'$ thus equality. Please is my proof correct?

Comment: Basically yes. The details need to be done for a complete proof of course, and you need not only $S' \subset E\setminus E'$ but also $S' \supset E\setminus E'$. You probably didn't mention that in the comment because that's the obvious part. Will you write your proof in an answer?

Comment: @DanielFischer Of course I'll write details! Thank you very much for all what you did! I'll start writing the proof as an answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer just started but I'm afraid I missundertood you. The proof you're asking me to write, is it the one you helped me to find or the one I already found before posting the question?

Comment: I thought of the one we sketched out here in the comments. But you could, if you want, also write the other [or only the other].

Comment: Ok then if you want I'll also write the other (I won't start now)

Comment: @DanielFischer I wrote the proofs.

Answer (score 1):

## Proof sketched in the comments.

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ a closed set. Thus $E'\subset E$.

Therefore $E=E'\cup (E\backslash E')$.

Let $x\in E\backslash E'$.

We have $x\notin E'$ thus $x$ isn't an accumulation point,i.e., $\exists\rho (x)>0,\,(x-\rho (x),x+\rho (x))\cap E=\{ x\}$

Set $\delta (x)=\frac{\rho(x)}{3}$. Obviously: $$\forall x,y\in E\backslash E',\, x\neq y\Rightarrow [x-\delta (x),x+\delta (x)]\cap [y-\delta (y),y+\delta (y)]=\emptyset\tag{1.0}$$

Set $N_x=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{\delta (x)}\right\rfloor+1$ where $x\mapsto\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ is the floor function and let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such as $n\ge N_x$.

We have $\frac{1}{\delta (x)}<N_x\le n\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}<\delta (x)$

Thus: $$\forall n\ge N_x,\,x-\delta (x)<x<x+\frac{1}{n}<x+\delta (x)\tag{1.1}$$

Set $S_x=\{ x+\frac{1}{n}\,/\,n\in\mathbb{N}\cap [N_x,\,+\infty)\}$. According to $(1.1)$:
$$S_x\subset (x-\delta (x),x+\delta (x))$$

Set $S=\bigcup\limits_{x\in E\backslash E'}S_x$.

Let $x\in E\backslash E'$ and set the sequence $\{ x_n\}$ defined by: $\forall n\ge N_x,\,x_n=x+\frac{1}{n}$. We have $\forall n\ge N_x,\,x_n\in S_x\subset S$. Since $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}x_n=x$ therefore $x$ is an accumulation point of S,i.e., $x\in S'$. Thus $E\backslash E'\subset S'$.

Let $y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash E$.

$E'\subset E$ thus $y\notin E'$. Therefore $\exists\varepsilon >0,\,(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap E=\emptyset\tag{1.2}$

**Case 1:** Suppose that: $\forall x\in E\backslash E',\,(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S_x=\emptyset$ then $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S=\emptyset$. Thus $y\notin S'$.

**Case 2:** Suppose that: $$\exists x_0\in E\backslash E',\,(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S_{x_0}\neq\emptyset\tag{1.3}$$

According to $(1.2)$, $x_0\notin (y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )$. Thus $x_0\le y-\varepsilon $ or $x_0\ge y+\varepsilon $. But since we have $(1.3)$, according to $(1.1)$ we can't have $x_0\ge y+\varepsilon$ ($(1.3)$ won't be true) and $y-\varepsilon <x+\delta (x_0)$ ($(1.3)$ won't be true).

Suppose the existence of $x\in E\backslash E'$ different than $x_0$ and that satisfies too $(1.3)$. We can suppose $x_0<x$ (otherwise substitute $x$ by $x_0$). We have then $x_0<x\le y-\varepsilon <x_0+\delta (x_0)$. Thus $x\in (x_0-\delta (x_0),x_0+\delta (x_0))$. Therefore $[x_0-\delta (x_0),x_0+\delta (x_0)]\cap [x-\delta (x),x+\delta (x)]\neq\emptyset$ which contradicts $(1.0)$. Thus:$$\exists !x_0\in E\backslash E',\,(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S_{x_0}\neq\emptyset\tag{1.4}$$

We choose for $\varepsilon $ the half of its initial value in case of $x_0=y-\varepsilon $ so that we get $x_0< y-\varepsilon $. Let's prove that $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S_{x_0}$ is a finite set.

Set $L=(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S_{x_0}$ and $\delta =\frac{y-\varepsilon -x_0}{2}>0$. We have $L\neq\emptyset$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}x_0+\frac{1}{n}=x_0$. Thus: $\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\ge N,\,x_0+\frac{1}{n}\in (x_0-\delta ,x_0+\delta )$. Since $x_0+\delta<y-\varepsilon $ therefore $\forall n\ge N,\,x_0+\frac{1}{n}\notin (y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )$. Thus $L\subset\{x_0+\frac{1}{n}\,\,|\,\,n\in\mathbb{N}\cap [N_{x_0},N)\}$ which is a finite set. Thus $L$ is finite.

We have:$(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S=\bigcup\limits_{x\in E\backslash E'}(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S_x$ $$=((y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S_{x_0})\cup\bigcup\limits_{x\in (E\backslash E')\backslash \{x_0\}}(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S_x$$

According to $(1.4)$: $\forall x\in E\backslash E',\, x\neq x_0\Rightarrow (y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S_x=\emptyset$. Thus: $\bigcup\limits_{x\in (E\backslash E')\backslash \{x_0\}}(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S_x=\emptyset$. Therefore $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S=L$. Obviously, $y\notin S'$.

We conclude by contraposition that: $\forall y\in S',\, y\in E$. Thus $S'\subset E$.

We have $E\backslash E'\subset S'\subset S'\cup E'$ and $E'\subset S'\cup E'$. Thus $E'\cup (E\backslash E')=E\subset S'\cup E'$.

On the other hand, $E'\subset E$ and $S'\subset E$. Thus $S'\cup E'\subset E$.

We conclude that: $E=S'\cup E'=(S\cup E)'\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\blacksquare$

## The other proof.

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ a closed set.

Let $x\in E$.

Since $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}\cup (\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathbb{Q}\cap (\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q})=\emptyset$ therefore either $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ or $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$.

For simplisity, set $\mathbb{A}=\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ such as $x\notin\mathbb{A}$.

$\mathbb{A}$ is dense on $\mathbb{R}$. Thus there exists a sequence $\{ x_n\}$ of elements of $\mathbb{A}$ such as $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}x_n=x$. Obviously, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,x_n\neq x$.

Set $S_1=\{ x_n\,/\,n\in\mathbb{N},x\in E\}$

Let $x\in E$. Since $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}x_n=x$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,x_n\in S_1$, we have $x\in S_1'$. Thus $E\subset S_1'$.

We will now construct a subset $S\subset S_1$ such as $S'=E$. The reason is that we may habe $S_1'\not\subset E$, so we have to "remove" the elements of $S_1'$ that aren't in $E$. To remove an accumulation point, you have to remove a neighborhood of the accumulation point from $S_1$. We'll do that in a way that won't affect any element of $E$.

Let $y\in S_1'\backslash E$.

If $\forall\delta >0,\, (y-\delta ,y+\delta)\cap E\neq\emptyset$ then $y\in E'$ since $y\notin E$. But $E$ is closed thus $y\in E$ which is a contradiction.

Therefore: $$\exists\delta (y)>0,\,(y-\delta (y),y+\delta (y))\cap E=\emptyset\tag{2.1}$$

Set $S_y=S_1\backslash (y-\delta (y), y+\delta (y))$. Obviously $y\notin S_y'$.

Set $S=\bigcap\limits_{y\in S_1'\backslash E}S_y'$.

Let $y\in S_1'\backslash E$.

Since $S'\subset\bigcap\limits_{y\in S_1'\backslash E}S_y'$ and $y\notin S_y$ therefore $y\notin S'$. Thus $S'\cap (S_1'\backslash E)=\emptyset$. And since $S\subset S_1$ therefore $S'\subset S_1'$. Thus $S'\subset E$.

Let $x\in E$.

Suppose that $x\in (S_1'\backslash E)'$, i.e:$$\forall\delta >0,\exists y\in S_1'\backslash E,\,y\in (x-\delta ,x+\delta)\backslash\{ x\}\tag{2.2}$$

Set $\Delta=\{\delta (y)\,/\,y\in S_1'\backslash E\}$

We have $\Delta\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $\Delta\neq\emptyset$ and $\Delta$ is bounded below by $0$. Thus $\Delta$ has an infimum.

Set $d=\frac{\inf\Delta}{2}>0$. According to $(2.2)$: $\exists y\in S_1'\backslash E,\,y\in (x-d,x+d)$. We have $d<\delta (y)$. We easly get: $y-\delta (y)<y-d<x<y+d<y+\delta (y)$ which contradicts $(2.1)$.

Therefore $\exists\delta (x)>0\, (x-\delta (x), x+\delta (x))\cap (S_1'\backslash E)=\emptyset$.

We can find a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such as it doesn't accross any interval $(y-\delta (y),y+\delta (y))$. Thus $\exists N_x\in\mathbb{N},\,\forall n\ge N_x,\, x_n\in S$ because the terms extremely near $x$ weren't removed. Since $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}x_n=x$ we have $x\in S'$. Thus $E\subset S'$.

We conclude that: $E=S'\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\blacksquare$

Comment: The first is close. At the beginning, you write "We choose $\delta(x)$ such ...", but an argument needs to be made that it is possible to do that. (Not hard, for $x\in E\setminus E'$ let $\rho(x) > 0$ such that $(x-\rho(x),x+\rho(x))\cap E = \{x\}$, then take e.g. $\delta(x) = \rho(x)/3$.) And one mistake (my fault), we cannot generally have $S' = E\setminus E'$, since $S'$ is closed. Look at $E = \{0\} \cup \bigl\{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\bigr\}$. But the construction gives us $S' = (E\setminus E') \cup (E\setminus E')'$. Show that $S'\supset E\setminus E'$ - that's immediate ...

Comment: ... from the construction - and then that $S'\subset E$. Do the latter by showing that an $y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus E$ is not a limit point of $S$. There is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon) \cap E = \varnothing$. For $x\in E\setminus E'$ with $x > y$, we have $(y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon) \cap S_x = \varnothing$. Why?. There is at most one $x \in E\setminus E'$ with $x < y$ such that $(y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon)\cap S_x \neq \varnothing$. Why? If there is one, why can $(y-\varepsilon/2,y+\varepsilon)\cap S_x$ contain only finitely many points?

Comment: In the other proof, you can't assume $\inf \Delta > 0$, you must expect $\inf \Delta = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your comments. So guess one of the obvious things that I didn't prove is false since I can't find where's the mistake in the proof about $S'=E\backslash E'$. We agree that $E\backslash E'\subset S'$ is correct so the problem is in the proof of $S'\subset E\backslash E'$ but I can't find it (guess in the **Existence**). Anyway I'm going to do as you said as hints.

Comment: Sorry, missed the ping. The wrong thing is "We take a neighborhood that doesn't come accross any interval $(x-\delta(x),x+\delta(x))$". That does not exist if $a$ is an accumulation point of $E\setminus E'$. In that case, every neighbourhood of $a$ contains infinitely many such intervals.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your good manners but please give up saying Sorry at least with me since I'm really grateful to you for giving me your time. About the comment well "We take a neighborhood that doesn't come accross any interval $(x-\delta (x),x+\delta (x))$" is for my absurde proof (I supposed $a$ isn't in any such interval nor its endpoints so it's between these intervals as shown in this [picture](http://www.mediafire.com/view/dwb75ddghe1ssrt/Neighborhood.jpg). $(A,B)$,$(C,D)$ and $(E,F)$ are the intervals $(x-\delta (x),x+\delta (x)$ and $a$ is our point and $(G,H)$...

Comment: @DanielFischer ... is it's neighboor that contains no point of $S$ but an infinity of points of $S$ since $a\in S'$, absurde. Thus $\exists x\in E\backslash E',\,a\in (x-\delta (x),x+\delta (x))$.

Comment: Consider $E = \{0\} \cup \bigl\{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\bigr\}$. Then $E' = \{0\}$, and every neighbourhood of $0$ contains all but finitely many of the $1/n$, and hence all but finitely many of the intervals $(1/n-\delta_n, 1/n+\delta_n)$.If you take an $a\notin E$, then you have a neighbourhood meeting at most two of the $(x-\delta(x),x+\delta(x))$, and then the argument works. But if $a\in E$ is a limit point of $E\setminus E'$, then it doesn't work, since every neighbourhood of $a$ meets infinitely many of these intervals.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes you're right! Thanks!

Comment: @DanielFischer I started to try fixing $\inf\Delta =0$ problem. I'll rectify as you told me the first proof later.
The set $D(y)=\{\delta >0 /(y-\delta ,y+\delta )\cap E=\emptyset\}$ is nonempty and obviously bounded above, so the $\delta (y)$ used in the proof will be exactly: $\delta (y)=\sup D(y)$.
Now suppose that $\inf\Delta =0$. Let $\varepsilon >0=\inf\Delta$. Thus $\exists y\in S_1'\backslash E,\,\delta (y)<\varepsilon$. Since $\sup D(y)=\delta (y)<\varepsilon$ therefore $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap E\neq\emptyset$ thus $\exists x\in E,\,y+\delta (y)<x<y+\varepsilon$ or...

Comment: @DanielFischer ...$y-\varepsilon <x<y-\delta (y)$ which is $\delta (y)<|x-y|<\varepsilon$. Thus we proved that $\forall\varepsilon >0,\exists (x,y)\in E\times S_1'\backslash E,\,0<|x-y|<\varepsilon$.
Taking $\varepsilon=1$, we find $x_1$ and $y_1$. Taking $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, we find $x_2$ and $y_2$ and so one. Taking $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we find $x_n$ and $y_n$. Thus, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,0<|x_n-y_n|<\frac{1}{n}\Rightarrow\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} x_n-y_n=0$. I want to find a contradiction using $y\notin E$ and $y\notin E'$, but I can't say...

Comment: @DanielFischer ... $\{x_n\}$ converges to an element of $E$ neither $\{ y_n\}$ converges to an element of $S_1'\backslash E$ (if only one was correct we get an accumulation point). Can you please help me?

Comment: @DanielFischer Now for the sketched proof. The proof of $E\backslash E'\subset S'$ is the same as in the proof written in the answer. Let's prove that $S'\subset E$. Let $y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash E$. If $y\in E'$ then $y\in E$ since $E$ is closed wich is a contradiction, thus $y\notin E$. Therefore $\exists\varepsilon >0,\,(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon)\cap E=\emptyset$. Let $x\in E\backslash E'$. Obviously $x\neq y$. Suppose $x>y$. Since $(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon)\cap E=\emptyset$ therefore $y+\varepsilon<x$ and since $\forall n\ge N_x,\,x<x+\frac{1}{n}$ therefore...

Comment: @DanielFischer ...$(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon)\cap S_x=\emptyset$. Now suppose that $x<y$. Since $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon)\cap E=\emptyset$ therefore $x<y-\varepsilon$. If $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap S_x=\emptyset$ we're done. If not, let's first prove that we can have only one point like that. Suppose that $\exists x_1,x_2\in E\backslash E',\,x_2<x_1<y$ and $(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon)\cap S_{x_i}\neq\emptyset$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$. Set $\mathbb{L}=\{ x_2+\frac{1}{n}\in S_{x_2}/x_2+\frac{1}{n}\in (y,y+\varepsilon)\}$ and...

Comment: @DanielFischer ...$L=\{ x_2+\frac{1}{n}\in S_{x_2}/x_2+\frac{1}{n}\in (y-\varepsilon,y)\}$. These two sets are finite: Since $x_2<y-\varepsilon$, setting $\delta=\frac{y-\varepsilon-x_2}{2}>0$ we have $(x_2-\delta ,x_2+\delta )\cap (y-\varepsilon,y)=\emptyset$ and since $x_2\in S_{x_2}'$ (in fact its only accumulation point) therefore $\exists N_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\ge N_\varepsilon,\,x_2+\frac{1}{n}\in (x_2-\delta, x_2+\delta)$. Obviously $L\subset\{ x_2+\frac{1}{n}/N_{x_2}\le n<N_\varepsilon\}$ thus $L$ is finite (same proof for $\mathbb{L}$ is finite)...

Comment: @DanielFischer ... By the way this proves more generally that if $x\in E\backslash E'$ such as $x<y$ and $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon)\cap S_x\neq\emptyset$ then $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon)\cap S_x$ contains finitely many points. Now, if $L=\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{L}=\emptyset$ then $y\in S_{x_2}$ since $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon)\cap S_{x_2}\neq\emptyset$ and we're done (we can there remove with the same way elements of $S_{x_1}$ unless again $y\in S_{x_1}$. Anyway $y\notin S'$). Now if $L\neq\emptyset$ or $\mathbb{L}\neq\emptyset$...

Comment: @DanielFischer ... If $L\neq\emptyset$ set $l=\max L$. Set $\varepsilon_1=\frac{y-l}{2}>0$. We still have $(y-\varepsilon_1,y+\varepsilon_1)\cap E=\emptyset$ and we have obviously $L\cap (y-\varepsilon_1,y)=\emptyset$. We do the same for $\mathbb{L}$ taking this time $\ell=\min\mathbb{L}$ and setting $\varepsilon_2$. Set $\varepsilon'=\min\{\varepsilon_1 ,\varepsilon_2\}$. $(y-\varepsilon',y+\varepsilon')\cap S_{x_2}=\emptyset$ so we get at most one $x$ for $(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon)\cap S_x\neq\emptyset$. This proves that we can always find a neighborhood of $y$ that contains finitely...

Comment: @DanielFischer ...many points of $S$. Thus $y\notin S'$. This proves that $S'\subset E$ by contraposition. Now let's prove that $E=S'\cup E'$. Let $x\in E$. If $x\in E\backslash E'$, since $E\backslash E'\subset S'$ we get $x\in S'$. Thus $x\in S'\cup E'$. If $x\in E'$ obviously $x\in S'\cup E'$. Thus $E\subset S'\cup E'$. $E$ is closed thus $E'\subset E$ and we proved that $S'\subset E$ therefore $S'\cup E'\subset E$. We get $E=S'\cup E'=(S\cup E)'\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\blacksquare$

Comment: @DanielFischer Please did you notice my comments? Guess you didn't since you didn't answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer Except if you didn't notice my comments, can you please tell me why aren't you answering?

Comment: Apologies. I got some pings, hadn't time to deal with them immediately, postponed ... and forgot :(

Comment: I haven't yet looked at the $\Delta$ thing. For the other, you can simplify the argument by noting that if $x_1,x_2\in E\setminus E'$ with $x_2 < x_1$, then we have by construction $x_2 < p < x_1$ for all $p \in S_{x_2}$. So if $(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon) \cap S_{x_0} \neq \varnothing$, then $x_0 \leqslant y-\varepsilon$ and we have $S_x\cap (y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon) = \varnothing$ for all $x\in E\setminus E'$ with $x < x_0$, and for $x\in E\setminus E'$ with $x > x_0$ it follows that $x > y-\varepsilon$, hence $x \geqslant y+\varepsilon$ by the choice of $\varepsilon$, and thus ...

Comment: ... $(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon) \cap S_x = \varnothing$. However, it need not be true that $(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon) \cap S_x$ is finite for all $x\in E\setminus E'$. That intersection is infinite if $x = y-\varepsilon$. But you can avoid that possibility by choosing $\varepsilon > 0$ so that $(y-2\varepsilon,y+2\varepsilon) \cap E = \varnothing$. But even if you don't avoid the possibility $y-\varepsilon \in E$ you still have that $y\notin S'$ since the only limit point of $S_x$ is $x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your comments. No problem! People can forget! In Arabic, the words for humans (الناس) and someone who forgot something (ناس) are as you can see close. That's a really much easier way to prove that $S'\subset E$. Thank you! I'll edit the answer of the sketched proof. For the problem of $\inf\Delta=0$ you can take your time. Personnally I didn't gave it up, but I still can't solve it (the second term of our universty started 2 weeks ago so I didn't thinked much since last comment).

Comment: @DanielFischer When editing the answer, I noticed something about your previous comment: "and for $x\in E\backslash E'$ with $x>x_0$ it follows that $x>y-\varepsilon$, **hence** $x\ge y+\varepsilon $by the choice of $\varepsilon $". But what if $x_0<x$ and $x<y-\varepsilon$? We must take a bigger $x_0$.. in fact the $\sup$. But that is pretty complicated since that choice leads to $x_0\le y$ with $x_0\in (E\backslash E')'$.

Comment: No, we had the assumption that $(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon) \cap S_{x_0} \neq \varnothing$. Since $S_{x_0} \subset (x_0, x_0+\delta(x_0))$, it follows that $x_0+\delta(x_0) > y-\varepsilon$. But for every $x\in E\setminus E'$ with $x > x_0$ we also have $x > x_0 + \delta(x_0)$ by the choice of the $\delta$s. So everything larger than $x_0$ cannot lie below $(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon)$ and hence lies above.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, everything larger than $x_0$ cannot lie below $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )$, in fact can't lie below $x_0+\delta (x_0)$ as you proved. But I dont' see why it means that it must be $>y$. Working on it using supremum of such points of $E\backslash E'$ which are $<y$ is possible. About what I said in my previous comment, this supremum can't be $y$ since $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap E=\emptyset$ and thus $(y-\varepsilon ,y+\varepsilon )\cap (E\backslash E')=\emptyset$. So this supremum is $<y$ but the supremum may not be an element of $E\backslash E'$.

Comment: Our assumption is that $S_{x_0}\cap (y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon) \neq \varnothing$. That means we have $x_0 \leqslant y-\varepsilon < x_0 + \delta(x_0)$. And for $x\in E\setminus E'$ with $x > x_0$ we have $x \geqslant x_0 + \delta(x_0) > y-\varepsilon$. Therefore we cannot have an $x\in E\setminus E'$ between $x_0$ and $y$ (between $x_0$ and $y+\varepsilon$ even).

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh I see. I understand. Thank you and sorry for bothering you!

Comment: @DanielFischer I edited the sketched proof in the answer. Please is my redaction good?

Comment: You have forgotten one or more words in the sentence after $(1.4)$ ["We for $\varepsilon$ the half of its value ..."], and you can simplify the argument more, but it's correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes you're right! My bad, the correct sentence is "We choose for $\varepsilon$ the half of its initial value...", so yes two words! Thank you very much for your help and for all the attention you gave me! Didn't gave up completing the other proof, I'll think about it next summer. It was nice talking with you!